# How to access SAP Fiori Launchpad with SAP Fiori Client (internal URL)

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, sap-fiori

I tried accessing our Fiori Launchpad with SAP Fiori Client. At first, I checked the connection in browser. This URL did not work:

> server not found

[https://host.domain:port/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=&sap-language=EN](https://host.domain:port/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=%3Cclient%3E&sap-language=EN)

The server could only be accessed this way:

[https://serverIPaddress:port/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=&sap-language=EN](https://%3Cserver%20IP%20address%3E:%3Cport%3E/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=%3Cclient%3E&sap-language=EN)

The URL using the server IP address is only working in browser. In SAP Client I get a **certificate error** because the SSL certificate is issued for the hostname and not for the IP.

What I did also try to connect with SAP Fiori Client:

- Using HTTP instead of HTTPS
- Using Hostname with and w/o VPN connected

Is there any way to access Fiori Launchpad with SAP Fiori Client when using an internal URL?

Comment: Have you already looked at the [Configuration Properties](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e2ed9b4f3edb4391a7a89b1af84d9606/3.1.0/en-US/fa599554d6fd44e6b0998683267deef2.html) in the SAP Help Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was easier than I thought. I just forgot to configure the proxy on mobile. This way I could reach the hostname and access SAP Fiori Client.